# Pass Argument to EventListener function

Tags: javascript

I'm building a simple calculator app. I'm trying to accomplish three things:

1. Assign an event listener to the buttons.
2. When the button is clicked, fire an event.
3. Use the eventListener function to display the value of the clicked button.

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
       var btnVal = btn[i].value;
       btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() { displayNumber(btnVal) }, false);
   }

   function displayNumber(param) {
       displayedNum.innerHTML = param;
   }
   ```

It seems btnVal is not accessible when passed to the event listener function.

Comment: Why can't you define that function in terms of `this` on the button itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining event listeners (or other asynchronous things) inside of a loop is tricky. You may think you're creating several different `btnVal` variables, one for each time through the loop, but you're not. That var btnVal gets hoisted to the top and reused, so your code ends up behaving like this:

```
var btnVal;
for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
   btnVal = btn[i].value;
   btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() { displayNumber(btnVal) }, false);
}
```

So all of your event listeners are interacting with the very same variable, and when they eventually get clicked, they'll only see the very last value that was assigned to btnVal, which should be `btn[btn.length -1].value`. All the values earlier in the array are lost.

There are a few ways you can address this:

1) Rather than depending on a closure variable, you could pull it from the element itself when the event goes off.

```
for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    displayNumber(event.target.value);
  });   
}
```

2) Move the event listener creation into a function, and pass btnVal in. Since it's now a function parameter, it gets a new binding.

```
for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    createListener(btn[i], btn[i].value);
}

function createListener(element, val) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function () { displayNumber(val) }, false);
}
```

3) you can do it inline using an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

```
for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
   (function (button) {
       button.addEventListener("click", function () { displayNumber(button.value) }, false);
   })(btn[i]);
}
```

EDIT: added option 4

4) If you can use ES2015, use `let`. Let has block scope, and will get a new binding each time through the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
   let btnVal = btn[i].value;
   btn[i].addEventListener("click", function() { displayNumber(btnVal) }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment won't work like that. Instead, use the target's value

```
for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
     displayNumber(e.target.value) 
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use btnVal inside the event.

It should look like this

```
for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
 btn[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var clickedButton = event.target || event.srcElement;
    console.log(clickedButton.value)
 }, false);
}
```